# Criar elemento HTML dinamicamente através do JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Estou tentando criar um botão dinamicamente através do JavaScript. Acho que estou fazendo tudo certo, mas o botão não aparece na minha página. Podem me dar dicas de como resolver?

```
function createButtonA() {
  var buttonA = document.createElement("button");
  buttonA.innerHTML = "Clique aqui";

createButtonA();
```

Comment: Mostra o html onde esse botão será criado, vc adicionou algum id ao html?

Comment: Mostre o seu HTML... atente-se a criar um exemplo [Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-mínimo-completo-e-verificável). Você também não fechou as chaves da sua função.

Answer (score 0):

A criação do elemento está correta, porém você apenas criou o elemento e não adicionou ele no DOM.

Você pode adicionar ele diretamente no body, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```js
function createButtonA() {
  var buttonA = document.createElement("button");
  buttonA.innerHTML = "Clique aqui";
  document.body.append(buttonA);
}

createButtonA();
```

> Documentações:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append